# How to: match (search space) against (join with column from other table)

Tags: sql, mysql, full-text-search

I'm lousy at SQL queries so this may be a silly question. However, here is roughly what i'd like to do:

> table corpuses //stuff i'd like to search thru
>      title
>      body
>      ...
>
> table searches  //list of search terms to be applied to corpuses
>      term
>      ...

The query i'd like to write is more or less as follows: I beleive I need some sort of a join, but I'm not sure just how to do that. Additionally, I'm not sure that the against() operator will take anything aside from a literal - the docs didn't seem to mention either way.

> select * from corpuses where match
>   (title, body) against (select term
>   from searches);

I'm using MySQL 5

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Thanks!
Brian

Comment: Please post more detail of your table structures when you ask questions like this.  "SHOW CREATE TABLE corpuses" and same for searches.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to use a FULLTEXT matching expression in your join condition.

I've never used a fulltext match in a join condition, so I'm not sure this will work, but hypothetically this might do it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.*
FROM corpuses c JOIN searches s 
  ON (MATCH(c.title, c.body) AGAINST (s.term));
```

---

Okay I've tried it using your table definitions and some sample data from the MySQL manual.  Here's a query that works (tested with MySQL 5.1.30):

```
SELECT *
FROM corpuses 
WHERE MATCH(title, body)
  AGAINST ( (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(term SEPARATOR ' ') FROM searches) 
    IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Comment: upon further inspection this is not actually what i needed - group concat lumps all of the terms in as one; i need to distinguish them from one another, so i think i'm back to square one.  thanks for the suggestions though.

Comment: It pays to be clear about your goals when you ask questions.  Good luck.