# Can a Fulltext matching expression work inside a join condition

Tags: mysql, join, full-text-search

This is a related to another question asked here: [How to: match (search space) against (join with column from other table)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496799/how-to-match-search-space-against-join-with-column-from-other-table)

But I wanted to post this as a follow-up to one of the answers which the author said he had not tried, and to see if anyone could confirm it.

> Sounds like you need to use a FULLTEXT
>   matching expression in your join
>   condition.
>
> I've never used a fulltext match in a
>   join condition, so I'm not sure this
>   will work, but hypothetically this
>   might do it:
>
> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT c.*
> FROM corpuses c JOIN searches s 
>   ON (MATCH(c.title, c.body) AGAINST (s.term));
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried a query like that out of curiosity and it failed for a very clear reason:

> AGAINST takes a string to search for, and an optional modifier that indicates what type of search to perform. The search string must be a literal string, **not a variable or a column name**. -[MySQL Manual on fulltext searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match) (my emphasis)

Check out Bill Karwin's [updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/496897/1128734) in the question you referenced to suggest a query using a subselect, which would select each row from table A that matches ANY value in a 'term' column from table B.